# When I cite content from a book, should I say "section 2.3.2.1 of book... " or "section 2.3.2.1 of `the` book ..."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I asked a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/419575/247356) based on a book.

> section 2.3.2.1 of book "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic
>   Perspective"

in this case, should I say "section 2.3.2.1 of book... " or "section 2.3.2.1 of `the` book ..."?

Answer (score 5):

You would not say:

> …section 2.3.2.1 of book *Machine Learning*…

At very least, it would have to be:

> …section 2.3.2.1 of the book *Machine Learning…*

But in this specific context, where you are citing a publication, you could also simply have:

> …section 2.3.2.1 of *Machine Learning…*

In fact this last form is perhaps the most common, and it’s certainly how I would write it.

Comment: I’m sure I said the same thing at one point. I got the back of her hand, and the edge of her tongue for being cheeky. 

Comment: Although the mighty APA appears to agree with Mrs. Smith: https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/07/punctuation-junction-punctuation-before-quotation-marks.html And now I think about it, her rule was not a comma before all quotes, but a comma before quoted direct speech.

Comment: @jonathanjo, I don’t mind if it goes. Feel free. (But just know that if, as a result, Mrs. Smith comes back to haunt me for not explaining my lack of commas earlier in my reply, then I’ll refer her to you! )

Comment: @tkp ; I was taught you place a comma where you would pause if you were talking. So, yes the comma is correct. At least the way I talk, it's correct

Comment: @jonathanjo, right but it at least acts to soften your earlier, “everything I’ve ever seen”, no?  Anyway, taking your comment about italicization of titles, I’ve modified the examples, rendering the P.S. redundant. Of course future readers will have no clue what you and I are talking about down here in the comments, but I think they’ll survive.

Comment: That looks better, upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **the** book as it is a specific book and not any old book.

> **the** definite article (PARTICULAR) used before a noun to refer to a particular thing because it is clear which thing is intended:[Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/the)